# Why am I getting this error message after I obtained my Laravel project from my GIT repository?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php, laravel-5.4

I am new in **Laravel** and I have the following problem.

I developed a Laravel 5 project on an old computer, and I put the code on a GIT repository. I retrieved my source code on my new laptop from the repository.

But I am facing problems while running the Laravel project on Apache and I am obtaining this error message on my Laravel website instead:

```
Warning: require(C:\xampp\htdocs\HotelRegistration\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\HotelRegistration\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\HotelRegistration\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\HotelRegistration\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17
```

The **C:\xampp\htdocs\HotelRegistration\bootstrap\autoload.php** is present in my project

Why am I facing this issue? What is the problem? What am I missing? How can I fix this issue? How can I try to solve this issue?

Comment: Is the `C:\xampp\htdocs\HotelRegistration\vendor/autoload.php` present, too? It's the file that's reported to be missing.

Comment: @RomanHocke ah no it is missing. Why? Is it some library that I have to reimport with composer or in some other way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to run

```
composer install
```

command to install packages. By default `vendor` directory is ignored when committing to GIT (this is good) so if you pull data from repository you need to install all packages running above command.